# How to redirect url with query string to another url with a query string using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

First, let me start by saying I'm not very skilled with .htaccess. I did search through StackOverflow and found many redirect examples, but couldn't find one to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm trying to redirect specific URLs with query strings to a different URL with a query string. The query string values are dynamic.

For example, I'd like to redirect this:

```
https://www.example.com/page/?search=search_string&param1=whatever&param2=whatever
```

To this:

```
https://www.example.com/?s=search_string
```

In the first URL, I don't care about any parameters except for the '**search**' value. The value for 'search' in the first URL will be the value of 's' in the second URL. I want to drop all other parameters. Keep in mind that the value for 'search' in the first URL is dynamic.

I tried the following with no luck:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/?$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `mod_rewrite` here to be able to examine and capture values from `QUERY_STRING`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)search=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ /?s=%1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked great. Out of curiosity, why would you specify a 302 as opposed to 301 status?

Comment: Since `301` is permanent redirect, I kept it `302` for testing purpose only. Once you've verified make it `301`.